# Getting order ID when querying for purchased items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I'm looking at [querying owned items](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases), and it doesn't include getting Checkout order IDs that are available when user actually makes a purchase. Is there no way to query the order ID for a purchase that have already been made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList ownedSkus = 
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
   ArrayList purchaseDataList = 
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
   ArrayList signatureList = 
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
   String continuationToken = 
      ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

   for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
       String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
       JSONObject jpurchase = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
       String orderid = jpurchase.getString("orderId");
       Log.v(TAG,"ORDER ID :"+orderid ); 
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, there's where it is! Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to know if the payload is also there? I haven't set everything up to make a purchase and see for myself yet.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yes `developerPayload` will be there also with `purchaseData`.

Answer (score 8):

The [example](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases) given by Google (and listed in another answer) is slightly wrong. When retrieving the `ownedItems` bundle, it does not contain `INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE` but rather `INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST`.

This is the list of keys you can get from the `ownedItems` bundle (though you may not get all of them all the time):

- `RESPONSE_CODE`
- `INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST`
- `INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST`
- `INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST`
- `INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN`

See [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases) for descriptions of them.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out... Damn